# Переход на новую строку

Tags: php, файлы

Допустим есть файл где храниться ID переписок пользователя построчно, но я не могу использовать константу `PHP.EOL` для перехода на новую строку т.к. мне надо получить **только** ID переписки, который потом пойдёт для построения пути вида `$file = './Messeges/M_ID/' . $id . '.txt'`. Или порекомендуйте альтернативный способ, как убирать константу.

Comment: Прочитайте http://php.net/manual/ru/function.trim.php

Comment: \n не катит? Или в чём тут дело?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как уже писал [Visman](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/186083/visman), обратите внимание на функцию [trim](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.trim.php).
Однако также порекомендую прочитать про [манипуляции с типами](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.type-juggling.php)

## Обработка уже имеющейся переменной с ID

```
$myId = " 23 ";
// Переведём в число
$myId = (int) $myId;
```

Это число можно спокойно использовать для формирования пути к вашему файлу:

```
$file = "./Messages/M_ID/{$id}.txt";
```

## Обработка файла с айдишниками

```
// Откроем поток для чтения
$f = fopen('chat_ids.txt', 'r');
// Предопределим массив для ID
$ids = [];
// Пройдёмся построчно до конца файла
while(!feof($f)) {
  // Прочитаем и очистим от пробельных символов
  $id = trim(fgets($f));
  // Если со строкой всё в порядке, преобразуем в число и запишем в массив
  if(is_numeric($id)) $ids[] = (int) $id;
}
// Закроем поток чтения
fclose($f);
// На выходе у нас есть массив только чисел типа Integer
// К примеру возьмём третий айдишник из списка
$id = $ids[2];
```

Comment: а почему не `${id}`?